# Android Database Simple rawQuery

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I was created a simple rawQuery in my main activity but it's not working. Cursor is not working but my database is already in this PELE folder in External Storage. Please help me what is the problem

My helper class is:

```
    public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String LOGTAG="EXPLORECA";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Adatbazis.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String FILE_DIR="PELE";


    public Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + FILE_DIR
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Az adattábla elkészült");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


}
```

And here is my main Activity.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Spinner helysegvalaszto, tagvalaszto, reszletvalaszto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        helysegvalaszto();

    }

    public void helysegvalaszto(){

        dbHelper= new Helper(this);
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();


        ArrayList<String> helysegek = new ArrayList<String>();


        Cursor Chelyseg = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT Helykod.h_kod, Helykod.h_nev from import1 JOIN Helykod on import1.helyseg=Helykod.h_kod", null);
        Chelyseg.moveToFirst();

        String hely = "";

        while (!Chelyseg.isAfterLast()) {
            hely = "" + Chelyseg.getString(Chelyseg.getColumnIndex("h_nev"));

            helysegek.add(hely);
            Chelyseg.moveToNext();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                helysegek);


        helysegvalaszto.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }


}
```

Thank you for help :) :)

Comment: You haven't created the table itself! that why your getting this error

Comment: What exactly is not working? You have to describe in detail what the problem is, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: I created tables in desktop and after I copied in external Storage.

Comment: My error is: no such table: import1 (code 1): but the table is in this database :(

Answer (score 0):

By extending SQLiteOpenHelper, you tell android the name of db and all structure you want to create in db. Along with tables' schemas etc. For using a pre-populated db you need to make use of [SqliteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

**Step 1**
Add Following to your app's gradle file in dependency section:
`compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'`

**Step 2**
In your project structure in `app/main/src` create directory named `assets`.
Inside `assets` create directory named `databases`.

**Step 3**
Place your `adatbazis.db` in `databases` direcotory.

**Step 4**
Change `Helper` class code to following

```
public class Helper extends SQLiteAssetHelper{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jain.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thenk you for help. But i need .... app.... Before start app user copies this Adatbazis.db in PELE folder in external storage and then start app. The app is opening this copied database. :)